# How to use one ZF2 module as a third part library?

Tags: yii, zend-framework2, autoload

Mainly the question is about ZF2 but the main task is how to integrate ZF2 to Yii.

If it's ZF1 I just have to include files that I need. 
ZF2 has a little bit more complex stucture.

Particularly I need to load ServiceManager module.

I've tried that:

```
$loader = new Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader();
$loader->registerAutoloadMap(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/Zend/ServiceManager'));
$loader->register();
```

And got an error:

```
Warning: include(/Project/lib/Zend/ServiceManager): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in /Project/lib/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php on line 186

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/Project/lib/Zend/ServiceManager' for inclusion (include_path='/Project/lib:.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear') in /Project/lib/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php on line 186

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Loader\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Map file provided does not return a map. Map file: "/Project/lib/Zend/ServiceManager"' in /Project/lib/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 /Project/index.php(14): Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader->registerAutoloadMap('/Project/...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Project/lib/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php on line 88
```

According to [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html) do I need set namespace description in config array before?

Could someone give an example please how to include only one module?

**UPDATE 1:**

Also I've tried this one:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';

$l = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader();
$l->registerPrefix('Zend', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/Zend/') );
$l->register();
```

It works. After that I called:

```
use Zend\Debug;
Zend\Debug::dump($l);
```

This rerurns an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Debug' not found in ...
```

**UPDATE 2:**

this code works for me:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';

$l = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader();
$l->registerNamespace('Zend', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/Zend'));
$l->registerPrefix('Zend', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/Zend') );
$l->register();
```

Now I can include Zend library anywhere in project. 
Anyway I would be glad to see others solutions

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against your proposed solution because it's a bit of a hack. One of the neat things about ZF2 is that it makes you explicitly define your dependencies so that your application can easily talk with them. You could therefore install Yii as a dependency through composer:

```
"yiisoft/yii": "dev-master"
```

If you install it through Composer, your class autoloader will be updated with references to your Yii framework. It will therefore allow you to access these files through a FQCN, i.e.:

```
use Yii\Path\To\Class as YiiClass;

...

$yii = new YiiClass();
```

Or:

```
$yii = new \Yii\Path\To\Class();
```

Using Composer also allows you to keep up to date with latest releases (you'd just re-run your composer script and it would install it all for you).

Answer (score 2):

I have several scripts which reside outside of the ZF2 normal areas and I need to use random functions of the framework. The simplistic solution I've found is:

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

require_once 'init_autoloader.php';

\Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require_once 'config/application.config.php');
```

There is nothing special about these files as they come standard with ZF2 Skeleton App.

Now I can use any ZF2 function.